# Нужна ли запятая перед "и" в указанном предложении?

Tags: пунктуация

"Юридическое лицо, которое получает деньги в кредит и обязуется вернуть их в указанный срок."
p.s. данное предложение является всплывающей подсказкой, которая появляется при наведении на заёмщика.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Союз "И" соединяет однородные "получает" и "обязуется". Запятая не нужна.